# What is minimum android version requirement for implementing seekbar in android?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

What is minimum android version requirement for implementing seekbar in android?
The Seekbar value is not shown in OPPO - Android v6.0

Comment: Seekbar is available since API 1, it means that the problem is in your layout.

Comment: Android Seekbar was added in the API LEVEL 1 checkout the official documentation here 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar

Comment: You should post your layout code and other relevant code of how your app is using the seekbar. As said in above comments SeekBar is available from API Level 1 and should work (if implemented correctly) on device running android version 6